# How can I access array index in Kohana

Tags: kohana-3

I am getting the result set in an array. Now I am trying to access the id that is the first index of the array but getting an error. Please let me know how to access the indexes of array.

```
$email_template = DB::query(Database::SELECT,"select * from mail_settings where id = " .$email['id'])->execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a Database_MySQL_Result object, not an array.

This will be correct.

```
$email_template = DB::query(Database::SELECT, 
                         "select * from mail_settings where id = " .$email['id'])
                         ->execute()->current();
```

Answer (score 0):

When you just run the `execute` method on a query, you get back a **Database_MySQL_Result** object.

To return an array instead, use the `as_array` method like so:

```
$email_template = DB::query(Database::SELECT,
                         "select * from mail_settings where id = " .$email['id'])
                         ->execute()->as_array();
```

Now you will be able to access the resultset as an array.

If all you want/need is the first or current row from the query, you can use the `current` method which you can read more about in the **Kohana_Database_MySQL_Result** class:

```
$email_template = DB::query(Database::SELECT,
                         "select * from mail_settings where id = " .$email['id'])
                         ->execute()->current();
```